# Find the radius of a circle touching two arcs within a square

Tags: geometry, circles, tangent-line

$ABCD$ is a square having each side = $6$ cm. Two arcs are drawn within the square as shown in the figure. Find the radius of the circle (centre $P$ in the figure) which touches both the arcs and the side of the square.
[image]

Comment: What you have tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is only a matter of pythagorean theorem:
[image]

Comment: In fact, if the side length of the square is $s$, then $r=s/6$.

Comment: @amd. Yes exactly.

Answer (score 1):

let the radius of the little circle be $r$. Let X be the point on BC where this little circle is tangential to BC. Let the angle PBX be $\phi$. Consider the triangle PBX
\begin{eqnarray*}
sin \phi = \frac{r}{6-r}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now condiser the triangle ABP ... Its sides are of length $6,6+r , 6-r$ and the angle at $B$ satisfies $cos \theta = \frac{r}{6-r}$. Now apply the cosine rule to this triangle.
\begin{eqnarray*}
(6+r)^2=6^2+(6-r)^2-2 \times 6 (6-r) \frac{r}{6-r}
\end{eqnarray*}
Solving this we have $\color{red}{r=1}$.
[image: Diagram]

Comment: Thank you for edited my answer. You have corrected an error & added a diagram (This is fantastic). I need to learn how to do diagrams like these ... can you suggest a nice peice of software for this ? ...  thank you again. $\ddot \smile$

Comment: I used Desmos for graphing.

Comment: Right ... Desmos ... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2254969/intersection-of-two-isometric-cubic-graphs ... levap gives another really nice example of this software here. Thank you, just what I was looking for.