# Intersection of two isometric cubic graphs

Tags: geometry

Let $f(x)=x^3+kx$, where $k$ is a real constant. Suppose that I have two pieces of transparencies with the graph of $y=f(x)$ on each of them, and I  overlay them (I can reverse one of the transparencies to obtain a mirror image of the original graph) and count the number of points of intersection of the two graphs (suppose that the two transparencies do not coincide completely). The maximum number of points of intersection depends on the value of $k$, and it cannot be larger than 9.

I worked on the following two cases years ago:
(1) If one of the graph is a rotational image of the other graph about its centre, then the number of points of intersection cannot be 9 unless $k<-\sqrt{8}$.
(2) If one of the graph is a reflectional image of the other graph, then the number of points of intersection cannot be 9 unless $k<-\sqrt{3}$.

For the cases that one of the graph is a rotational image of the other graph about some point other than its centre, and the case that one of the graph is a glide reflectional image of the other graph, I find it too difficult and don't know how to deal with them.

Comment: Nice question. Just so you can play with it and see the results in your own eyes, I've made a desmos application where you can choose $k$, the angle of rotation ($u$) and the center of rotation ($(a,b)$) and see how the graphs intersect: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ypffqlpays. Enjoy your investigation!

Comment: @levap Desmos : This looks like a very useful online resource. Thank you for bringing it to my attention.... & the example you have created is brilliant ...$\ddot \smile$